# Save a single google sheet as PDF on drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I found the below code on here to save a google sheet to PDF on drive but my issue is that it saves all the sheets. I need to save just the "PRINT PO' sheet.

I need help with the following:

- save just one sheet named 'PRINT PO'
- place URL of the PDF on the drive in a cell:

  ```
  function saveAsPDF()
  {
      const folderName = `Purchase Orders`;
      const fileNamePrefix = `PO`;

      DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folderName)
      .next()
      .createFile(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
      .getBlob()
      .getAs(`application/pdf`)
      .setName(`${fileNamePrefix} - ${Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 
          `GMT-8`, 
          `yyyy-MM-dd`)}`));
  }
  ```

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48794209/1595451 ,  https://stackoverflow.com/q/65756215/1595451

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Apps Script: How to save (Just one) Google Sheet to Drive Folder as PDF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48794209/google-apps-script-how-to-save-just-one-google-sheet-to-drive-folder-as-pdf)

Comment: Hey, I get this as an error when I run the script - 'Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property getFolderById on object DriveApp.'